# Access violation writing location error when i try to read from file

Tags: c++, visual-c++

this is where i write to a file ->

```
void Supermarket_Billing_System::Add_and_WriteNewProduct(Product P)
{
    ofstream fl;
    fl.open("ProductList", ios::out | ios::binary);
    fl.write((char *) &P, sizeof(P));
    fl.close();
}
```

this is where i read from a file ->

```
void Supermarket_Billing_System::Read_DisplayProductFromProductList()
{
    Product P;
    int x;
    ifstream fp;
    fp.open("ProductList", ios::in);
    fp.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    fp.read((char *) &P, sizeof(P));
    x = P.GetProduct_qty();
    fp.close();
}
```

Product class looks like this ->

```
class Product
{
private:
     long int Product_no;
     std::string Product_name;
     double Product_price;
     int Product_qty;
     double Product_tax;
     double Product_dis;

public:

    //Constructor
    Product();
    Product(long int, string, double, int, double, double);

    //All Getters methods
    long int GetProduct_no();
    string GetProduct_name();
    double GetProduct_price();
    int GetProduct_qty();
    double GetProduct_tax();
    double GetProduct_dis();

    //All Setters methods
    void SetProduct_no(long int);
    void SetProduct_name(string);
    void SetProduct_price(double);
    void SetProduct_qty(int);
    void SetProduct_tax(double);
    void SetProduct_dis(double);

    void Accept_Product();
    void Accept_ProductForBilling();
    void Display_Product();
};
```

When i try to read from the file by calling Read_DisplayProductFromProductList() it gives me error ->

Unhandled exception at 0x6803ad54 (msvcp100d.dll) in Supermarket_Billing_System.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xfeeefeee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Product` class is not trivially copyable due to the `std::string` member; you are not writing the actual string that `Product_name` holds in your write method, only the binary representation of a `std::string`, and the internal string pointer will almost certainly point to an invalid location when you read. Either way attempting to perform a bytewise copy of a non-trivially copyable class is undefined behavior.

You also haven't passed the `binary` flag when you open your file for reading

```
fp.open("ProductList", ios::in);
```

which will cause issues on Windows if there are any \r\n (0x0A 0x0D) sequences in the file you are reading.

You will either need to use a `char` array for your string, or manually handle the serialization of each member. The simplest way would be to use [stream friend functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/output-operator.html) to write your object to a plain text file

Answer (score 1):

I believe you shouldn't read into std::string like if it were a POD (plain old data). `std::string Product_name` is a member of your `Product` class and when you read from the stream, it likely spoils the string.

Similarly, you shouldn't write `std::string` like that (as part of `Product`).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue, when i did write operation on a file using ofstream in a gSOAP client. However when i switched to FILE (stdio.h) and fwrite() the access violation error was gone!

Answer (score -1):

It may because the open file error. You can print the return value to see if it is NULL.
When you compile your code.

Pay attention to the warning message. Sometimes, it may just a warning when you compiler, but got a crash when you run it.

Comment: Hi Jie Yin! Welcome to stackoverflow (well, I guess you've been lurking around for a while). While your answer may or may not be wrong in a general case, for this specific question, there are already answers that address the original poster's question. You may find it helpful to read some of the pages on answering questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering such as  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. If you have other questions, try https://stackoverflow.com/help. Good luck!

Comment: What I am said is for another situation for the error **Access violation writing location error when i try to read from file**. Cause I got this error and didn't find answers in stackoverflow. I think the answer has contribution in it and can make the community to be better. We actually don't need make it too rigid. Any contribution is acceptable, right? It is possible that other people may get to the same space as me and find answer from it. That's my though. You will impact my passion on it if you forbid I seriously answer questions.

Comment: The question title is only a title. The question details are what need to be answered. If you didn't find the answer to your question on stack overflow, but you figured out the answer, you can ask and answer your own question, allowing future searches to benefit from what you have shared, while keeping the answers to the current question focused on the current details. Should you decide to do so, It is helpful to be detailed to keep it from being marked as a duplicate. I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi hlongmore! I got you. I will create question in the future for those same title and different specific errors.